# Websphere Application server (BASE version) Not starting up

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

Websphere Application server(BASE version 8.5.5.12) servers not started After upgrade IBM SDK from 8.0.4.5 to 8.0.5.27, App's are up with SDK 8.0.4.5 with out any issue's, issue with only after upgrade the SDK 8.0.5.27.
Nothing to be recorded in the logs. can you please assist so why we are facing this issue.

Comment: When you start the server from the command line, are you certain there is no indication of any problem with server startup either from the console or any of the log files (SystemOut.log, SystemErr.log, native_stdout.log, native_stderr.log or FFDC)?

Comment: Probably you upgraded SDK using `root` user, and servers are running with different one. So double check permissions. Also try to start server from command line, (startServer nameOFServer), maybe you will get some more info.